# PY QT using QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

I am using  PY QT for making GUI. There is multiple tabs , in one of tab it has tablewidget of 3 rows and 3 column. I am trying than when ever  user click any row of column 2, it gives pop up check box window. I don't know how to tract the clicking of perticular cell and then activate the related def.

Answer (score 1):

QTalbeWidget have a signal named "cellClicked".

You can use it like this below.

```
myTableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.OnCellClicked)

def OnCellClicked(self, row, col):
    pass
```

Comment: that will allow popup on clicking of anywhere in whole table.